# Need Suggestion to Swipe through Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` on `didSelectrowAtIndex` it pushes to a `viewController` which shows the detail on `UIScrollView` which is vertically scrollable.
Now I need that If I tap on any row it would be pushed to the same `viewController` and shows the detail of selected row,Additionally I need to have the Swipe Functionality to see the data for all rows in `tableview` instead of go back & select another row.
I know it can be achieved by `UIPageControl` or `[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];`,But I am wondering If  there is any better approach to do the same or I should go with any of these two,If yes then Which one is better?
Please Help Guys.....Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance....:)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are plenty of approaches to achieve what you want. You should keep in mind that `UIPageControl` has limitation on number of items (dots) displayed (over 20 items would overlap). Also, it would be appropriate to have next/previous buttons for the users preferring tapping buttons instead of swiping/panning. I prefer using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`s and buttons on toolbar for navigating between items.

Answer (score 0):

The key, in my opinion, is to control how many UIKit controls are held in memory at the same time. However you implement this, you want to make sure that you have solution that holds UIKit controls for the currently visible child element only, or perhaps the previous and next ones, too, but not for the full array (especially if you're dealing with `UIImageView` objects).

One control to consider is `UIPageViewController`. At first blush, it might look complicated, but in reality it's quite simple and offers a nice way to swipe between various "pages" while not holding all of the pages in memory at the same time. See [View Controller Catalog for iOS: Page View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3).

If you decide to implement a scroll view with paging enabled, I'd suggest specifying the `delegate` and implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to add and remove subviews as appropriate. This is historically what I've done, but I now lean towards page view controllers.

There are also a ton of third-party implementation of "infinite scrollers", which implement this sort of functionality, though I can't vouch for any particular one.